# Iterate through the chars in a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In C++ I have an array of strings, say:

```
string lines[3]

lines[0] = 'abcdefg'
lines[1] = 'hijklmn'
lines[2] = 'opqrstu'
```

is there a way to loop through the chars within each index as well as loop through the indexes? something like `lines[i[j]]`?

Comment: I have a string array with 9 indexes of lines each with 9 chars, so basically a 9x9 box of chars and I'm trying to write a script to test if a sudoku game was solved correctly. The first thing I did was just read each line of length 9  from a txt file into a string array of size 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
std::string lines[3];

lines[0] = "abcdefg";
lines[1] = "hijklmn";
lines[2] = "opqrstu";

for (int i=0; i < lines.length(); ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < lines[i].length(); ++j) {
        std::cout << lines[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the 'std::' do? I'm very new to c++ and have been trying to only use the built in stuff so far, just beginning to learn to import librarys

Comment: @AustinMW `std::` is the `std` namespace with the scope operator, `::`. it's usually preferred to use `std::` because sometimes functions from namespaces can overlap and can result in ambiguity. It's a good habit when working with multiple code bases or libraries.

Comment: The `std` in front of `string` is the _namespace_ for the `string` class.  You can avoid using it in your code if you have `using namespace std` at the top of your source `.cpp` file.

Comment: Ah ok, the 'using namespace std' has been in the hello world template I've been using and I hadn't got around to looking up what it did

Answer (score 3):

If you have C++11, you can use range for loop and auto:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

   std::string lines[3];
   lines[0]="abcdefg";
   lines[1]="hijklm";
// for( auto line: lines)//using range for loop and auto here
   for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
   {
       std::string::iterator it= lines[i].begin();
       //for ( auto &c : line[i]) //using range for loop and auto here
       for(; it!= lines[i].end(); ++it)
       {
           std::cout<<*it;
       }
       std::cout<<"\n";
  }

}
```

O/P

abcdefg

hijklm

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string arr[3];

    arr[0] = "abcdefg";

    arr[1] = "defghij";

    arr[2] = "ghijklm";


    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (auto it : arr[i]) {
            std::cout << it;
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Use a double loop. For each line, iterate through each character.
Using a double index isn't exactly allowed like this: `arr[i,j]` or `arr[i[j]]`; it needs to be `arr[i][j]`.

But, if you're using a `std::string`, you need just either iterate over the `str.length()` or just use `for (auto it : str)`, where `str = THE TYPE OF std::string`.

Comment: How does this work with an array of `std::string`?  The OP is using `std::string`.